# How come my flood fill doesn't ever recur?

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array, return, flood-fill

I've been trying to create a game where you can click on blocks and adjacent blocks of the same color disappear. However, when I run my code, only blocks to the right of the clicked one disappear and I don't know why. After `return;`, shouldn't my algorithm recur back to the last time floodfill was called? I should also mention that I'm using libgdx 3 for my game.

```
private static void floodfill(int x,int y, Color color) {   
        if (x>=10 || y>=15 || x<0 || y<0) {
            System.out.println("sap");
            return;
        }
        if (!blockSprites[x][y].getColor().equals(color)) {
            System.out.println("sas");
            return;
        }
        blockSprites[x][y]=null;
        
        floodfill(x+1,y,color); //right
        floodfill(x-1,y,color); //left
        floodfill(x,y-1,color); //down
        floodfill(x,y+1,color); //up    
    }
```

Comment: You should try to determine what the expected behavior is vs what you're getting. Do you have some example input / output? Are the system calls printing when you expect them to?

Comment: @user16320675 That was it! I just didn't notice it because when my floodfill method gets called for the first time, it's already inside of a try/catch loop. When I put `blockSprites[x][y]=null;`  into a try/catch loop, it worked instantly.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be inside of a try/catch loop.

```
try {
    if (!blockSprites[x][y].getColor().equals(color)) {
        System.out.println("sas");
        return;
    }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    return;
}
```